# "this" inside of a nested prototype not pointing to instance

Tags: javascript

Given:

```
var x = function () {
};

x.prototype = {
    y: {
        z: function () {
            console.log(this);
        }
    }
};

var foo = new x();
foo.y.z();
```

Why is `this` logged in the `console` as `y` instead of `x` and how is that possible given `y` is a literal object without a constructor?

Comment: I don't think you're using prototypes right. You shouldn't assign a new value to the prototype. Always add stuff only. Like `x.prototype.y = function () { ..` instead of `x.prototype = { y: function () { ..`

Comment: @FritsvanCampen: There's nothing wrong with doing it like `x.prototype = {...}`. You shouldn't do it when extending native objects but if the object is your own that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @Frits, it's common to declare prototypes as one declaration as it performs slightly better than repeated member access.

Comment: @BrianCray This is a bottleneck in your code?

Comment: @xtal not a bottleneck, but something I had difficulty grasping.

Comment: Note that `this` is set entirely by **how the function is called**. Since you called `z` as a method of `y`, then `this` within the function will reference `y`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"Why is this logged in the console as y instead of x..."*

Because that's how JavaScript works. The `this` value is set as the object from which the method was invoked. Generally you should keep objects off of the `.prototype`. They're going to be shared among all instances created using the constructor.

---

> *"...and how is that possible given y is a literal object without a constructor?"*

It's easy. The `this` value is not tied to any constructor. It's a dynamic value that is set based on how you invoke a function or method.

---

There are utilities that let you manually override the natural value that `this` is set to in an invocation. Using the `.call` or `.apply` methods of the `Function.prototype` to invoke the method is one example

```
var foo = new x();
foo.y.z.call(foo);
```

Now `this` in the `z` method will be the `foo` object, because we manually set it by passing it as the first argument to `.call`.

The `.call` method sees that it was called as a method of the `z` method, and so it invokes `z` for you, but sets the `this` value of `z` to whatever you provided as the first argument... in this case the `foo` object.

---

But generally you won't use objects as values of the `.prototype`. The reason is that all instances created from the constructor get an implicit reference to the `.prototype` of the constructor, so updates to any objects on properties of the `.prototype` will be observed from all instances.

Comment: is it only under "use strict"; that this would not be the global (normally window) in the case of a literal object?

Comment: @BrianCray: Object literal is just a syntax for creating objects. It has no impact on the value of `this`. The value of `this` is set to `window` (or `undefined` in strict mode) only when there is no other value provided. In other words, if I invoked a function that is referenced from a variable instead of an object property, its `this` will be `window`

Comment: Example: `var foo = {bar:function() {console.log(this);}};` We have object literal syntax creating an object with a single `bar` property referencing a method. If we do `foo.bar()`, then `this` is the `foo` object. But if we do this: `var baz = foo.bar; baz();`, now `this` will be `window` even though we're invoking the very same function. We just detached it and assigned it to a variable.

Comment: Is there a better way to namespace things in prototypes then? For example, if I have pubsub methods inside my prototype, ideally they'd all be under events.on, events.off, etc.

Comment: @BrianCray: Depends on what you mean. You can create an extended prototype chain so that the `.prototype` object of the `B` constructor is an object that inherits from the `.prototype` of the `A` constructor, and so the objects that are created from `B` will inherit the methods from both contructor prototypes. It's not really namespacing, but it does allow different organization of code.

Answer (score 1):

To make this work, you need `y` to return the enclosing `this`.

```
var x = function () {};
Object.defineProperty(x.prototype, "y", { get: function() { return this; } })
x.prototype.y.z = function () { console.log(this); }

var foo = new x();
foo.y.z(); // x
```

Whatever is to the left of the `.` on `z()` is `this`. In your question, `y` returns the object literal: `{z:function(){...}}`.

Comment: Thanks for offering a way to achieve my intended outcome! I'm going to accept the system's answer since it answers my original question, but if I could accept two I would :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var y=Object.create({z: function () { console.log(this); }});
var x=Object.create(y);
y.z();
x.z();
```

You may use Object.create to create an object instead of using constructor.